# When using `Jade`, why is there an extra space added?

Tags: pug

```
  div.soldhere-title-large
    | find
    span.title-equal-span
      | =
```

There is no space after the `=`, but in my rendered HTML there is. Why does Jade do this and is there any way to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like to get rid of the space, the content needs to be applied inline:

```
  div.soldhere-title-large find
    span.title-equal-span =
```

Comment: This doesnt work for variables: span.title-equal-span #{myVar} will result in a space after mvyVar. Any ideas?